# How can I programmatically find the correct Microsoft Office product version number (and service pack)?

Tags: .net, ms-office

I'm having trouble finding a consistent version number for several Office products.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514511/how-can-i-determine-if-ms-office-2007-sp2-is-installed) led me to these KB articles which suggest different ways to find the service packs for [Office 2007](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/928116) and [Office 2010](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2121559) products.

However, the file versions of the Office .exe files are not consistent with the chart.

Using the Excel 2010 installed on my machine as an example:

- Help > About info from Excel: Microsoft Excel 2010 (14.0.6106.5005) SP1
- File version by viewing the properties of Excel.exe: 14.0.6106.5005
- Original file version (from table): 14.0.4756.1000
- SP1 file version (from table): 14.0.6024.1000

Is there a more reliable way to retrieve version numbers and service packs for Microsoft Office products?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We decided to back out of this because it was taking way too much time. However, I thought I'd post what I got in case anyone needs to take it farther.

First, here are the three relevant KB articles which list out the service pack versions:

- [Office 2003](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/821549)
- [Office 2007](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/928116)
- [Office 2010](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2121559)

Method 2 in these articles suggest the properties of the executable file is a reliable way to get the actual file version. Unfortunately, it isn't.

**Here's how you can find the executable**:

Find the install root for Office:

```
// version is one of these three: Office 2003 = 11, Office 2007 = 12, Office 2010 = 14
RegistryKey registryKey = 
    Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(String.Format(
        @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\{0}.0\Common\InstallRoot", (int)version));

if (registryKey == null)
    registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(
        registryKeyPath.Insert("SOFTWARE".Length, "\\Wow6432Node"));

if (registryKey != null)
    installRoot = registryKey.GetValue("Path").ToString();
```

Then append the name of the executable (with on exception for Office 2003):

- Access: MSACCESS.EXE
- Excel: EXCEL.EXE
- Outlook: OUTLOOK.EXE (use OUTLIB.DLL for 2003)
- PowerPoint: POWERPNT.EXE
- Word: WINWORD.EXE

With this information, you can **get the FileVersionInfo for the selected application**. Using Word as an example:

```
FileVersionInfo fileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(
    Path.Combine(installRoot, "WINWORD.EXE"));

if (fileVersionInfo != null)
    fileVersion = fileVersionInfo.FileVersion;
```

Theoretically, you could now compare this version number to the tables from the KB articles to find the correct service pack. This is where I abandoned my efforts for the reasons listed in the question - you'll find the version numbers just don't match up.

You can use code similar to below to **compare the versions** for, say Word 2010 SP1:

```
Version version = new Version(fileVersion);
if (version >= new Version("14.0.6024.1000"))
    servicePack = 1
```

Here's some code to **get the version of Office suite**:

```
string msodllPath = Path.Combine(
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles),
    String.Format(@"Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE{0}\MSO.DLL", (int)Version));

if (!File.Exists(msodllPath))
    msodllPath = msodllPath.Replace("Program Files", "Program Files (x86)");

if (File.Exists(msodllPath))
{
    FileVersionInfo msodll = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(msodllPath);
    FileVersion = new Version(msodll.FileVersion);
}
```

If you are trying to **get the edition name** (i.e. Professional, Ultimate, Student, etc) you are in for an adventure. Here's some *untested* code fragments that may be useful. It's different for each version of office and each edition so best of luck!

```
string fullNameRegistryKey = "";

if (Version == OfficeVersion.Office2010)
    fullNameRegistryKey = String.Format(
        @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Office{0}.PROPLUSR",
        (int)Version);
else if (Version == OfficeVersion.Office2007)
    fullNameRegistryKey = String.Format(
        @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\PRO",
       (int)Version);

RegistryKey installRootRegistryKey = GetSoftwareRegistryKey(fullNameRegistryKey);

if (installRootRegistryKey != null)
    FullName = installRootRegistryKey.GetValue("DisplayName")
        .ToString().Replace("Microsoft ", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

See if you can adapt this code:

[What is the best way to get Excel version?](http://p2p.wrox.com/excel-vba/82653-what-best-way-get-excel-version.html)

This code uses Application.ProductCode to determine the Office version. ProductCode is a property available in most Office products. I checked Outlook, Word, Excel and Access 2003 and all of them had it.

You may also be able to leverage this code:

[Display system and version information](http://www.everythingaccess.com/tutorials.asp?ID=Display-system-and-version-information)

This code takes the MSACCESS.exe filename and uses a Windows API to determine the version and assembly information, from which you would derive the service pack number.