# How can I find out version of MSWord on computer?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, ms-word

Can anybody help, please. How can I find out version of msword installed on computer? If there is few versions of it, find out that version which open '.doc' by default. Can anybody suggest some C++ functions or algorithm for this task? Sorry for bad english :( Thank you for help.

Comment: .doc files should be opened in Word 97 to Word 2003, although it can also be opened in later versions. .docx files should be opened in Word 2007 and later versions.

Comment: See a C# example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8144062/how-can-i-programmatically-find-the-correct-microsoft-office-product-version-num

Comment: Note that ".doc" files could by default be opened by OpenOffice.org. What should the result be in that case?

Comment: In OpenOffice case answer "OpenOffice" will be enought

Answer (score 0):

you can read the registry entry from the path.
for.....

- Office 2003 = 11
- Office 2007 = 12
- Office 2010 = 14

  HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Word\Registration{-------------}\AccessNameVersion

  HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Word\Registration{-------------}\ExcelNameVersion

  HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Word\Registration{-------------}\OutlookNameVersion

  HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Word\Registration{-------------}\PowerPointNameVersion

Comment: That's Office 12 (2007). Other versions have other entries.

Answer (score 0):

If I want to know what version of Word, I look at the registry key HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Application\CurVer

It will give you a ProgId like: "Word.Application.14", "Word.Application.12", or "Word.Application.11" for Office 2010, 2007, and 2003 respectively.  The part to the right of the last "." gives the version.  If you look at "Word.Document", it won't always give the correct answer because there are feature packs that can be installed that will allow an older version of Word to read a new version of Word document.  These feature packs update some registry settings for Word.Document, but they leave Word.Application alone.

Comment: This doesn't address the file association part of the question.

Comment: Depends on what he wants to do with the file...  If he wants to open the file, he can just use ShellExecute with the name of the .doc file and it will open with the default applicaiton.

ShellExecute(0, NULL, pszPathToFile, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);

Comment: When the question asked about "version" of Word, I interpreted that as literally finding the version number.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't go rummaging through the registry when there are APIs available.  Using the appropriate APIs will help make sure your test works for all versions of Windows and Word.

To find out which executable is registered to handle a certain file type (like .doc), use [AssocQueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773471%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Once you have the path to the executable, you can check its version number using [GetFileVersionInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647003%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [VerQueryValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647464%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If you just want to find out which versions are installed (regardless of which application is associated with .doc), you can probably query Windows Installer.  Check out [MsiEnumProductsEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [MsiGetProductInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

There's probably also a way to query for this stuff using WMI.